I have a question on US elementary schools. Would it be on topic?
The question I have in mind is inspired by this article.
Would it be on topic? It deals with teaching at a US elementary school, so not at tertiary level, but presumably many users here are familiar with US elementary schools and will be able to answer the question.

Have you checked https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ?

Or: Why is Academia.SE only for higher education?

@cag51 that's the funky thing. The linked question would actually suggest that it's on-topic (because high school questions is only off-topic insofar as the "user base of experts" necessary to answer the questions is not here). But teaching at high school level is within scope (ex: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/152273/will-tutoring-calculus-be-worthwhile-experience), which makes the lines blurry and unclear.

We also do not have the "user base of experts" for elementary school (we may be parents, former students, etc., but we are mostly not elementary school teachers, principals, reading coaches, etc.). As for the linked question, that is only on-topic because OP is asking about strengthening their PhD application.

@cag51 I'm sure there are more examples, e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104193/what-can-phds-offer-to-high-school-teaching-that-masters-graduates-cant, which certainly looks in conflict with the stated "education outside an academic setting, i.e., in high schools or similar" in the list of topics that one should avoid. But if I find more examples the natural result is you/other mods will close more questions, and I don't see how that's productive.

Closing off-topic questions certainly would be productive; however, I have always tried to err on the side of leaving borderline questions open, especially when they are interesting (and I have encouraged close-voters to adopt this view on many occasions). The question you linked this time is also on-topic because it is not only about high school; there is also a component about the value of a PhD degree. That said, I agree that further iterations of this example-finding-debate would not be productive; I have nothing more to say on this topic.

I don't see the relevance of bringing up high school when the article was about elementary school. There is a huge difference between teaching elementary school and teaching high school. Indeed, the progression/distinction elementary school -- middle school -- high school seems to me about the same as high school -- undergraduate work -- graduate work.


Would it be on topic?

Definitely not. See the help center. We don't even take questions about undergrad admissions or culture; elementary school is thus a fortiori proscribed.

presumably many users here are familiar with US elementary schools and will be able to answer the question

Presumably many users here are familiar with driving cars, but such questions remain off-topic.
